# Looking for an idiom or a slang word/phrase for a formal reply with no intent to help

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, idiom-requests

There is a word in Russian "отписка", which could mean "unsubscription" but also has in some context could mean "written reply in a very formal way with no intent to really help". Like a very polite "fuck off" reply.
So I feel like there should be a similar idiom or a slang word for this in English. Are there any?

Comment: The term "form letter" comes to mind.

Comment: [Here are Multitran's options for "отписка"](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0&langlist=2)

Comment: That sounds like _summary dismissal._

Comment: [***bureaucratic brush-off***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bureaucratic+brush-off%2Cbureaucratic+form+letter&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbureaucratic%20brush%20-%20off%3B%2Cc0) beats out ***bureaucratic form letter*** in NGrams.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider ***fob off***, a phrasal verb defined by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fob-off#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20%27fob%20off%27&text=If%20someone%20fobs%20you%20off,be%20fobbed%20off%20with%20excuses.%20%5B) in this way:

> If someone fobs you off, they tell you something just to stop you
> asking questions. [disapproval]
>
> Ex: I've asked her about it but she ***fobs
> me off***.
>
> Don't be ***fobbed off*** with excuses.

While this [Phrase Dictionary](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/fob-off.html) defines it as:

> To put off deceitfully; to attempt to satisfy with something of
> inferior quality or something less than one has been led to expect.

(at this link you will also find the origin of the phrase)